# Mass renaming (refactoring) in C# project

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, resharper

Today, I received an excel file with two columns. I have to rename objects in a solution according to excel file.

First column contains "current name", second column contains "new name". More than 5000 lines there.

Currently it is VS2013 with Resharper, C# solution contains several projects.

How can I automate this process?

Comment: Tool recommandations are off-topic.

Comment: What sorts of things are you renaming?  EG Is it down to the level of local variables?

Comment: The simplest solution comes to my mind: use some automation tool (like AutoIt) to record an action of replacing text (with Resharper for example) with data from first row from given Excel file and deleting this row, repeat 5000 times automatically

Comment: is resharper supports macros to get classes, properties etc and rename it in a loop? how?

Comment: @Peter M, no local variables are not important even if exists.

Comment: I think text replace is dengeraus. 2 dummy name: Person, PersonId. If i replace Person with something, PersonId also changes.

Comment: Sounds to me like you need some kind of script, perl perhaps that reads your from/to input file line by line and replaces the matches in all your *.cs files. You may use full word and case sensitive matches so you don't replace something you don't want to. I've done this a lot in linux environment. Perhaps, powershell.

Comment: One wonders at a management structure that could come up with this being something that needed to be done: I would consider the Proxy and Adapter patterns to avoid such an effort.

Comment: diffrent idea. resharper got an API.

 write a small plugin that will recieve csv with 

oldname,newname
oldname,newname
oldname,newname

that will call resharpers rename command on the solution

Comment: @Nahum Litvin, when it work it solves all my problem. Do you know, how ca i call resharpers rename command from addin, extension, macro etc. Now i'm looking it. I can get classes, properties etc. Only rename part required. Infact this can be question itsef.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately recent versions of Visual Studio have lost macros (essentially: not enough people using them). Thus the easiest path is unavailable.

As the other [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20972739/67392) notes (now deleted), doing this one name at a time with existing VS tools is possible, but clearly infeasible for 5000!

I would approach this by:

1. Look for other tools, even if they have a price the time saved is likely to be significant. If nothing found, try #2. Given a few months Rosalyn might be an option (or even a preview of it: you won't be putting this into production with customers I assume!).
2. Put together a simple search and replace in a script tool (eg. PowerShell: advantage of having access to the full .NET framework and inbuilt CSV support) to perform one substitution (and you'll need to decide to include or exclude comments and strings). Then repeat that for each renaming.

#2 is likely to need to few tries: false positives will be all too easy.

Comment: Search and replace as text will create to many hedaches, i guess. But macros sounds good. I can move project to vs2010 for refactoring only.

Comment: @Ayhan By the time you don't replace in comments and strings the only issue is keywords. There are not many keywords so those cases could be handled manually…. Remember the language has changed since VS2010: downgrading might break things itself because it does not understand newer features (eg. async).