# Rename all classes with filename in a folder by pattern C# - need to rename class, files and references

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio

I'm using Visual Studio 2017. 
This is not just renaming files. This is renaming classes with file name and reference. But on a mass scale.

Is there a way to rename all classes in a Namespace/folder.
I want to rename all classes like `myClassNameDTO` to `myClassNameInCache` and `myClassNameDTOMapper` to `myClassNameInCacheMapper`.

I have nearly 350 of such classes.

Is there a way i can make use of VS features or C# reflection.

Comment: is this duplicated? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12347881/renaming-files-in-folder-c-sharp

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Renaming files in folder c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12347881/renaming-files-in-folder-c-sharp)

Comment: It is not clear if you want to rename classes (actual name after the "class" keyword), filenames or both. Could you please make it clear?

Comment: You don't say what version or edition of Visual Studio you are using, nor if you have any third-party tools installed, but I believe the only feature of a default Visual Studio install that can help here is the compiler (i.e. writing your own code to do this).  Also, reflection works at run-time and won't help with source code.

Comment: I want to rename the actual classes and its references too

Comment: If "DTO" appears only in class names and not e.g. in method names, variables, etc. the command "Replace in Files" will help

Comment: @KlausGütter I cannot assume that. It is there.

Comment: @Dimitar I had that in the header.

Comment: I think this is one of those cases where programmers are tempted to waste more time looking for a perfect solution than it would take to just do it manually. At 10 seconds each, 350 classes is about an hour.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Mass renaming (refactoring) in C# project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20972666/mass-renaming-refactoring-in-c-sharp-project)

Comment: Actually for references you can do : Ctlr+R+R on class name and VS will do the rest. For filenames - probably it will need to be done manually. You can do the Ctrl+R+R on the type itself, but I recommend the first way.

Comment: @Dimitar Please read the question. I have 350+  classes to rename and all their file names and references. What i want to do is a mass ctrl+r+r